# How to fire xval validation when the data of text is generated dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, validation, xval

I do have three text box, where all are required field. which is tightly coupled with a model

Name* : 

Age*  :

**Check Button**

Date* : //This is a hidden filed

**Continue Button**

When i click on continue button all the validation error messages will get displayed.
i am entering the Name and Age then click on Continue. then the validation should fire for click on check button before continuing.

if i click on check button,date will be generated, and the validation error message still will be displayed on the page until i click on continue button.

I just want to clear of the validation message when click on verfiy button. how can i do that.

Comment: xVal doesn't actually do any validation, it just hooks into existing validation frameworks.
Which framework are you using?
Does the **Check Button** cause a postback, or does it do javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wire up the validation with dynamic content you can simply send down the xVal generated javascript with the content it should validate.